# Looking for a VirtualKey to real char converter function

Tags: c#, keyboard, raw-input

I'm looking for a function that receives a bunch of VirtualKeys at RawInput from a keyboard. A software pretty similar to a keylogger in C#. Just in case, I searched a damn lot and could find nothing.

**Context**

- To capture the event I use KeyPressed.
- To read the VKey value y access it from `e.KeyPressEvent.VKeyName`.
- For alphabetical chars works fine, `'A'->'A', 'B'->'B' and so on`.
- The rest of the chars won't, cases are:

  - A key combination char (which means I have to press more than one key from the keyboard to create them), for example `'@'->'AltGr + 2' or '$'->'Shift+5'`.
  - A simple number. Whenever I press any number: `'2' -> 'D2'`.
  - A special char that when I press `' ' -> SPACE`.

**What I need**

Whenever I press a button, I want to receive the exact value of it, not just "SPACE" or "OEMSEMICOLON". I need to get a single char with the value ' ' or ';' or whatever I press.

**The simple code**

```
private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, RawInputEventArg e)
{
    KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
    string keyChar = kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyPressEvent.VKeyName);
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed: " + e.KeyPressEvent.VKeyName);
}
```

**Sample from console**

[image: Values I get from keyboard vs values I need in '']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

such a function with all your specificities does not exist. You have to build the correspondence table.

the easy way is to build a first array or enum table with 256 virtual keycode or scancode  and a second array gives you the right translation virtualKey or scancode to string key

for example

```
public enum Key
{
        Escape = 1,
        D1,
        D2,
        D3,
        D4,
        D5,
        D6,
        D7,
        D8,
        D9,
        D0
}


private string[] stringCodeMap = {
            "",   //key = 0,
            "",   //key = 1,
            "1",  //D1 = 2,
            "2",  //D2 = 3,
            "3",  //D3 = 4,
            "4",  //D4 = 5,
            "5",  //D5 = 6,
            "6",  //D6 = 7,
            "7",  //D7 = 8,
            "8",  //D8 = 9,
            "9",  //D9 = 10,
            "0",  //D0 = 11
}
```

and you could trap the string code with : if scankey is the result of keypressed (virtual key or scancode key)

```
string skey = stringCodeMap[(int)scankey];
```

for multiple keys pressed, Control, shift (left or right).... have their own code

Comment: This would work! But I'm still pretty sure there must be already an implementation that will solve this (thinking about an Unicode parser or something like that). If there is no better answer, this will be the one.